# How to disable IntelliJ's indentation-based brace handling?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, indentation, braces

IntellIJ 2020.2 added `Indentation-based brace handling` for Scala mentioned on the website here [whatsnew](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#scala). How do I disable this feature? I've searched for keywords "indent brace" and "brace handling" and cant see a setting that would disable it under "Code Style -> Scala".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [IntelliJ Scala Plugin 2020.2: Indentation-based Brace Handling](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2020/07/22/intellij-scala-plugin-2020-2-indentation-based-brace-handling/) search for

```
Editor | General | Smart Keys | Scala | Control curly braces based on line indentation
```

[image]

Comment: Unchecking - Smart Keys | Scala | Add braces automatically. This worked. Thank you for the link.